# Django From wizard get form data from previous step

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I want to create a checkout or submit form as the last step of a form wizard.
It should display all data from previous steps and add a Captcha or 'Terms of service' checkbox.

I know how to modify the context for each step, but I can't find a way how to access from data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got the solution from the code base.

You need to call `WizardView.get_cleaned_data_for_step(step)`

Comment: Did you maybe misspelled it? There is [get_cleaned_data_for_step](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_cleaned_data_for_step).